# unable to find an inherited method for function 'distance' for signature '"matrix", "character"', but it's a df?

Tags: r, dataframe, matrix, character

Here is all my code leading up to the function as per @Till request!

```
library("phyloseq")
library("qiime2R")
library("vegan")

# read in phyloseq objects from qiime
physeq<-qza_to_phyloseq(
  features="~/Documents/qiime2-analyses/CRD/fresh_run/table.qza",
  tree="~/Documents/qiime2-analyses/CRD/fresh_run/rooted-tree.qza",
  "~/Documents/qiime2-analyses/CRD/fresh_run/taxonomy.qza",
  metadata = "crd-metadata.txt")

# Clean out unwanted taxa annotations. Base script removes endozoicimonaceae, escherischia,
# and shigella contaminates
physeq <- subset_taxa(physeq, Family!="f__Endozoicimonaceae")
physeq <- subset_taxa(physeq, Family!="f__Enterobacteriaceae")
physeq <- subset_taxa(physeq, Family!="f__mitochondria")
physeq <- subset_taxa(physeq, Class!="c__Chloroplast")

#pull out otu table
otu_table <- (as.data.frame(otu_table(physeq)))

# rotate otu matrix layout
rownames(otu_table) <- factor(rownames(otu_table), levels = rownames(otu_table))
otu_ord <- as.data.frame(t(otu_table[rowSums(otu_table)!=0, ]))

# remove any rows or columns with only 0s
otu_ord <- otu_ord[, colSums(otu_ord !=0)>0]
otu_ord <- otu_ord[rowSums(otu_ord[])>0,]

#edits from observations of this StO chat
rownames(otu_ord) <- gsub("sample-", "", rownames(otu_ord))
rownames(otu_ord) <- as.numeric(rownames(otu_ord))
otu_ord <- as.matrix(otu_ord)

#the args of the function
raup_crick_abundance = function(spXsite=otu_ord, plot_names_in_col1=TRUE, 
                                classic_metric=FALSE, split_ties=TRUE, 
                                reps=9999, set_all_species_equal=FALSE, 
                                as.distance.matrix=TRUE, report_similarity=FALSE){
```

Please note the whole function is verbatim from Stegen_etal_ISME_2013 github linked below [and here](https://github.com/stegen/Stegen_etal_ISME_2013/blob/master/Raup_Crick_Abundance.r).

I am receiving the error

```
    Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable)  : 
      unable to find an inherited method for function ‘distance’ for signature ‘"matrix", "character"’
Called from: (function (classes, fdef, mtable) 
{
    methods <- .findInheritedMethods(classes, fdef, mtable)
    if (length(methods) == 1L) 
        return(methods[[1L]])
    else if (length(methods) == 0L) {
        cnames <- paste0("\"", vapply(classes, as.character, 
            ""), "\"", collapse = ", ")
        stop(gettextf("unable to find an inherited method for function %s for signature %s", 
            sQuote(fdef@generic), sQuote(cnames)), domain = NA)
    }
    else stop("Internal error in finding inherited methods; didn't return a unique method", 
        domain = NA)
})(list("matrix", "character"), new("nonstandardGenericFunction", 
    .Data = function (physeq, method, type = "samples", ...) 
    {
        standardGeneric("distance")
    }, generic = "distance", package = "phyloseq", group = list(), 
    valueClass = character(0), signature = c("physeq", "method", 
    "type"), default = NULL, skeleton = (function (physeq, method, 
        type = "samples", ...) 
    stop("invalid call in method dispatch to 'distance' (no default method)", 
        domain = NA))(physeq, method, type, ...)), <environment>)
Browse[1]> traceback()
No traceback available
```

within [this function linked here](https://github.com/stegen/Stegen_etal_ISME_2013/blob/master/Raup_Crick_Abundance.r).

My argument is a data.frame (`dput()` below) with no character strings? As I understand it, the error is saying the function distance () can't be calculated with matrix or character strings, which I agree with...

Therefore, I am unsure why `distance ()` cannot operate with my arg, if I am interpreting the error correctly.

Thank you.

Here is my Qiime2 OTU table.qza [linked to this Dropbox file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/6qj2k4jwnh20a14/table.qza?dl=0), my rooted tree [linked here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ymk8uy04nbovt69/rooted-tree.qza?dl=0), and my taxonomy [linked here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/5qkg2ok8w97a1vr/taxonomy.qza?dl=0) to recreate my phyloseq object.

Comment: Your `col1` is of class `character()`. Notice the quotes around the numbers.

Comment: Please show how you are calling the function on your data. Are you simply doing `raup_crick_abundance(ex_otu_ord)` or are you setting any other preferences?

Comment: You can run `traceback()` to see exactly which `distance()` call in the function is causing the problem, edit the function to put a `browser()` line right before the problem, and then next time your run you can inspect the current state of your data and try to debug.

Comment: What package is this `distance()` function coming from?

Comment: I tried the `traceback()` but it received `no traceback available` @Till. I added the full debug/error to the original post.

Comment: There is no `distance()` function in base R, but many packages have a function with that name. Please post all the code you execute before calling the `raup_crick_abundance()` function, starting from a fresh R session. I tried the `ecodist` package. Which makes the `distance()` calls work, but then something else breaks.

Comment: @Till Updated above

Comment: Thanks. I took a look at the `phyloseq` package documentation and it says that the `distance()` function used in `raup_crick_abundance()` expects an `otu-table` or `phyloseq` object, but you are feeding it a `data.frame`/`matrix`.

Comment: Thank you very much.  I extracted the otu_table as a value `otu_table <- (otu_table(physeq))` and a matrix `otu_table_try <- as(otu_table(physeq), "matrix")` both of which yielded me the error `Error in sample.int(x, size, replace, prob) : 
  incorrect number of probabilities` I suspect I need to rotate my rows and columns for the spXsite?

Answer (score 1):

What the error message is actually trying to get across is that your matrix *has* character values and the function you called can not handle it. The first column in `data.frame` is a character column.

If your data frame is called `ex_otu_ord`, try this:

```
ex_otu_ord <- ex_otu_ord[-1]
ex_otu_ord <- as.matrix(ex_otu_ord)
```

Then try again to call the function on `ex_otu_ord`.

Comment: Thank you that's really helpful!  However, even after I removed the character column, I am still receiving the error.  I see that my rownames and colnames are characters, but should that matter?

Comment: I set the rownames and colnames to NULL but still received the same error above...